# Change order of symbols for «sort-lines»

Tags: sorting

I am using «sort-lines» to sort *include*s in C/C++ files before saving. The problem that arises is that a headers with `"` symbols sorted higher than ones with `<` symbols. But I want the reverse.

How do I change the order so, that the `<` character would have higher precedence than the `"` symbol?

Comment: You may need to write your own predicate function and call `sort-subr` directly. Or.. as a hack, you could advise `sort-lines` so that before the sort you swap `"` and `<` characters and then after the sort you swap them back. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort-regexp-fields`. Mark the region and do:

`M-x sort-regexp-fields` <kbd>RET</kbd> `#include .\(.*\)` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\1` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The regular expression group will capture everything after `#include "` or `#include <` and sort on that instead of the whole line.

FYI, I believe the reason for the sorting you're seeing is because `"` is higher than `<` in ASCII.

Comment: Thank you, I already thought about sorting by the name of a headers and ignoring the opening `<`, `"` symbols. But I came to conclusion, that headers sorted together this way looks a bit messy, that's why I want just to change the order of the characters.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I wrote a code to implement the hack that @glucas mentioned. It perhaps only suits the purpose of sorting headers in C, but I hope someone find it useful.

```lisp
(defun replace-char-after (character-number replacement)
  "Replaces char in the buffer after the `character-number' with `replacement'"
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char character-number)
    (delete-char 1)
    (insert-char replacement)))

(defun replace-delimiters (old-closing-char new-opening-char new-closing-char opening-point end-point)
  "Replaces delimiters between `opening-point' and the
`end-point'. Note, that the `opening-point' should point to the
opening symbol, thus the function seeks only the closing"
  (block replace-delimiters
    (let ((closing-point opening-point))
      (setq closing-point (+ 1 opening-point))
      (while (< closing-point end-point)
        (if (eq (char-after closing-point) ?\n) ;;no closing delimiter
            (progn
              (print "Err: no closing delimiter")
              (return-from replace-delimiters nil))
          (when (eq (char-after closing-point) old-closing-char)
            (progn
              (replace-char-after opening-point new-opening-char);;opening delimiter
              (replace-char-after closing-point new-closing-char);;closing delimiter
              (return-from replace-delimiters (+ 1 closing-point)))))
        (setq closing-point (+ closing-point 1))))))

(defun swap-<-and-quote-includes (beg end)
    "Swaps in the text between `beg' and `end' the matching «<» and
  «>» character to the \" quote, and vice versa. Mainly used
  before sorting to swap the order of these characters, next
  after the sort to restore the text."
  (block swap-<-and-quote-includes
    (let ((curr-point beg))
      (while (< curr-point end)
        (setq curr-point (+ curr-point 1))
        ;;first check «"»
        (if (eq (char-after curr-point) ?\")
            (progn
              (setq curr-point (replace-delimiters ?\" ?< ?> curr-point end))
              (if (eq curr-point nil)
                  (return-from swap-<-and-quote-includes t)))
          ;;else if «<»
          (if (eq (char-after curr-point) ?<)
              (progn
                (setq curr-point (replace-delimiters ?\> ?\" ?\" curr-point end))
                (if (eq curr-point nil)
                    (return-from swap-<-and-quote-includes t)))))))))
```

The function `swap-<-and-quote-includes` transforms every text like `<foo>` to `"foo"`, and every `"foo"` to `<foo>` within the given range *beg*, *end*.

And here's the code to find and sort headers:

```lisp
(defun sort-lines-nocase (reverse beg end)
  (let ((sort-fold-case t))
    (sort-lines reverse beg end)))

(defun c-sort-includes ()
  "Sorts #include statements"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let (beg end orig-content sorted-content)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (and (not (looking-at "#include "));;look for includes, if no then
                  (eq (forward-line 1) 0) ;;go one line down (if not EOF).
                  ))
      (setq beg (point))
      (while (and (looking-at "#include ")
                  (eq (forward-line 1) 0)));;to not hang cuz of EOF
      (setq end (point))
      (setq orig-content (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))
      (setq sorted-content (with-temp-buffer
                             (insert orig-content)
                             (swap-<-and-quote-includes (point-min) (point-max)) ;;swap characters < and > in includes
                             (sort-lines-nocase (point-min) (point-max)) ;;sort
                             (swap-<-and-quote-includes (point-min) (point-max)) ;;swap the characters  back
                             (buffer-string)))
      (when (not (string= orig-content sorted-content))
        (kill-region beg end)
        (insert sorted-content))
      )))
```

The function `c-sort-includes` seeks for the first paragraph of «#include »s, and sorts it. I have it added to `before-save-hook` with a code to only run it for C and C++ modes. Known cons: α) only the first paragraph with includes will be sorted. It's because search till the end of a file can be expensive — e.g. at my job I recently found a `.c` file with — can you even imagine?! — ≈16000 lines! Correct solution would rather be a minor mode, which would track where header blocks in the file reside. β) In older Emacs, from ≈2015 year, function could hang — it was a bug that later was fixed.